# Сложность с wp_insert_post

Tags: wordpress

Нужно добавить несколько постов.
Код в файле functions.php:

```
// Создаем массив данных новой записи
$post_data = array(
  'post_type' => 'cars',
  'post_title'    => 'title_111',
  'post_content'  => '12345678987456321',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'year' => '2018',
);

// Вставляем запись в базу данных
 wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

На экране выдает такую ошибку:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_user_logged_in() in C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\post.php:2160 Stack trace: #0 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\post.php(5886): _count_posts_cache_key('post', 'readable') #1 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(298): _transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #2 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(323): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #3 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #4 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\post.php(3965): do_action('transition_post...', 'publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #5 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\post.php(3425): wp_transition_post_status('publish', 'new', Object(WP_Post)) #6 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-content\plugins\ab_cars_plugin\functions.php(81): wp_insert_post(Array) #7 C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-content\plugins\ab_cars_plugin\ab_cars_plugin.php(22): require_once('C:\\OpenServ in C:\OpenServer\domains\wp.com\wp-includes\post.php on line 2160
```

После закомментировал строку:

```
//wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

Ошибка исчезла, а пост добавился туда, куда нужно. Подскажите, что у меня не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема заключается в том, что при создании поста вызвается функция is_user_logged_in(), а в functions.php она не используется. Таким образом нужно поменять логику вызова, например довив весь код для создания поста в функцию и повесить ее вызов на событие "init":

```
function insert_post_in_wp() {
    // Создаем массив данных новой записи
    $post_data = array(
        'post_type' => 'cars',
        'post_title'    => 'title_111',
        'post_content'  => '12345678987456321',
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_author'   => 1,
    );

    // Вставляем запись в базу данных
    wp_insert_post( $post_data ); 
}
add_action('init', 'insert_post_in_wp');
```

PS: Еще я удалил из массива параметр "year" - т.к. такого параметра не существует.

Comment: спасибо огромное, вот в чем загвоздка была...ща буду пробовать, а то собирался уже хардкорно вставлять данные в таблицу)

Comment: параметр "year" - это метаполе, которое тоже нужно вставить в массив аргументов.  Или оно по-другому вставляется?

Comment: По-другому, через update_post_meta()

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как мне в update_post_meta() передать ID  создаваемого поста?

Comment: Например, так $id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

Comment: я так и сделал, все работает, спасибо